# Horizontal text orientation for optional X grid lines in c3.js

Tags: javascript, graph, c3.js

I am using [c3.js](http://c3js.org/) in a web application to dynamically generate graphs by handing a JSON object to `c3.generate()`, and I use the optional X grid lines in a time series to show key events.

I want the caption text of the X grid lines to be displayed horizontally(or at least not rotated since the text is Japanese and lingually speaking Japanese text should not rotated when writted vertically) but the default seems to be vertical, and [this does not seem to be changable(using the standard settings)](http://c3js.org/reference.html#grid-x-lines).

If I view the DOM element information in Chrome, remove the rotate in the transform property and modify the position, I can make it horizonal with a sensible positioning, but I do not understand how to do that programatically(and dynamically, in a non-ugly way).

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you in advance.